# secure GALAXY TAB - how to disable Bluetooth and/or WiFi on kernel permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, kernel

Please be kind enough to support me with help me securing Galaxy tabs we give out for employees. Is there a way to disable the permission to stop accessing Bluetooth and WiFi...

"The easiest way to disable bluetooth is to just remove the permission in the 
bluetooth device. Bluetooth is managed by the kernel through the devices /dev/ttyHS0 
and /dev/ttyMSM0 and these devices have set read and write permissions (660) for the 
user and group bluetooth. If those permissions are removed, the device will not be 
reachable. This must be done when booting the system since the /dev directory is reset 
during reboot."

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to make changes to the system partition?  And are you able to prevent the users from making changes to the system partition?  Also don't forget USB and (if present) microSD interfaces as potential paths of data transfer.

Comment: which im abel to do so far is: antivirus guard, APN block internet sites except company sites, periodic audit on agreement, procedures on place. and SIM lock....

Comment: Phisical security is the only way to secure micro SB interfaces right? or is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to do on boot - what you will need to do is extract the boot.img from the device.

You can then unpack the boot.img which gives you a ramdisk & a kernel image. In the Ramdisk is a set of init files, init.rc is where you are going to want to either place your code to set up the persmission to this device *or* reference a script.

Does this help?