# android disable WiFi and Bluetooth service build

Tags: android

Im trying to develop service that starts by bootup receiver if the wifi or bluetooth is enabled automatically disable it.

please help me out

thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: IM going through tutorials and have found a way to boot load the service but does not know how to trigger the service if the wifi or bluetooth is disabled.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142195/secure-galaxy-tab-how-to-disable-bluetooth-and-or-wifi-on-kernal-permissions this is ma early post and still i did not get any answer that i can relay. so im still going through the dark forest in serch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".BootTimeServiceStarter" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And in your class file do the following

```
 public class BootTimeServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {


    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (bluetooth.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON
                    || bluetooth.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON) {
                    bluetooth.disable();
            }
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED
                    || wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }


            }
    }
```

Comment: hey thank you, i did this but when i install it on the phone. it dows not work.

Comment: onReceive will be called when you reboot your device

Comment: i have sent you a mail regarding this if not a hazel... to the mail address you have on the profile wemtyournds@gmail.com. please have a look. thank you